# JavaBean as Datasource in iReport: “General рroblem: null” (jar is in the classpath!)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, datasource, javabeans, ireport

I am using *JasperReports 5.6* via API. I am building a report using *iReport*. The problem is that I've already set a jar with bean factory in the classpath of *iReport* as

```
com.myname.beanproject.beanpackage.BeanFactoryClass
```

Also I set up static method to call a list of beans:

```
getListEntries
```

but still getting a error while testing a connection. What am I doing wrong?

Error is not helpful at all:

```
General problem: null
```

As I can see, the problem is not in classpath neither factory: when I change any, the error is changing either to

`"No class found"`

(if I add something to class name)

or

`"General problem: com.myname.beanproject.beanpackage.BeanFactoryClass.getListEntries11111()"`

(if I add 11111 to the name of factory method to test)

Comment: Do you have the same problem in case using just *Java* code?

Comment: I didn't test it with java code, because I needed to construct the report template before. I am not a ninja in Jasperreports xml, unfortunately, so I can't do that editing plain xml. I downloaded trial Jasperwave visual editor, and I managed to get javabean datasource in it, though iReport failed with the same conditions and settings. So, I think it could be a bug of iReport and it should work with java code. I can't tell because I decided to do that another way.

Answer (score 3):

Your `getListEntries()` method should be static and **public** too
that way , ireport can deal with it :)
i ran into the same problem, i had put my method like that

```
protected static getmyBeans().....
```

i fix the connection test after i put

```
public static getmyBeans().....
```

in my factoryClass
so check your method defenition
and dont forget to rebuild your jar code
and restart ireport
good luck, and sorry if i do mistakes in my english language

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. Your getListEntries() method should be static. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but my getListEntries() method was static that time, it's mentioned in my first post. Anyway, I a glad that it works for you.